# I want to creat a selection function with a checkbox

Tags: python, kivy

I working on a game encounter generator with python kivy and I want to create a function that when I uncheck the checkbox, it will generate a `random.choice()` except for unchecked one from the `race` list.

this is my code

```
import random
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.grid_2 = GridLayout()
        self.grid_2.cols = 2
        self.grid_2.size_hint = 1, 0.2
        self.grid_2.add_widget(Label(text="Number of enemies"))
        self.number = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.grid_2.add_widget(self.number)
        self.add_widget(self.grid_2)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Races", size_hint=(1,0.2)))

        self.grid_3 = GridLayout()
        self.grid_3.cols = 4
        self.grid_3.size_hint = 0.5, 0.5

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Human"))
        self.chk_human = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_human)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Elf"))
        self.chk_elf = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_elf)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Dwarf"))
        self.chk_dwarf = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_dwarf)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Orc"))
        self.chk_orc = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_orc)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Hobbit"))
        self.chk_hobbit = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_hobbit)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Viashian"))
        self.chk_viashian = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_viashian)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Goblin"))
        self.chk_goblin = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_goblin)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Leonim"))
        self.chk_leonin = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_leonin)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Nezumi"))
        self.chk_nezumi = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_nezumi)

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Naga"))
        self.chk_naga = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_naga)

        self.add_widget(self.grid_3)

        self.generate = Button(text="Generate", font_size=40, size_hint=(1,0.3))
        self.generate.background_color = 0.8,0.5,0.5,0.7
        self.generate.bind(on_press=self.Gerar)
        self.add_widget(self.generate)

        self.encounter_type = (Label(text="Type of encounter", font_size=20, size_hint=(1,0.1)))
        self.add_widget(self.encounter_type)
        self.show_enemies = Label(text="Click to Generate")
        self.add_widget(self.show_enemies)

    def Gerar(self, instance):
        self.show_enemies.text = ""
        int_number = int(self.number.text)
        type = ["NEUTRO", "HOSTIL", "ALIADO"]
        races = ["HUMANO", "ELFO", "ANÃO", "HOBBIT", "VIASHINO", "LEONINO", "NEZUMI", "GOBLIN", "NAGA"]
        classes = ["FIGHTER", "KNIGHT", "BERSERKER", "FENCER", "NINJA", "HOPLITE", "BEAST TAMER",
                   "DRAGON TAMER", "ARCHER", "ROUGE", "DOLL MASTER", "WARLOCK", "MAGE", "ACOLYTE", "MONK", "CLERIC",
                   "BARD", "WARLORD", "SHAMAN", "DRUID", "SPEAKER", "MERCHANT", "ALCHEMIST", "BLACKSMITH", "CHEF"]
        elements = ["FIRE", "AIR", "WATER", "EARTH", "LIGHT", "DARK"]

        for i in range(int_number):
            type_choice = random.choice(type)
            if self.chk_human is False:
                race_choice = random.choice(races-["HUMANO"])
            else:
                race_choice = random.choice(races)
            class_choice = random.choice(classes)
            element_choice = random.choice(elements)
            encounter = (race_choice + ' : ' + class_choice + '  -  ' + element_choice)

            self.encounter_type.text = "ENCONTRO: " + type_choice
            if type_choice == "ALIADO":
                self.encounter_type.color = 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 1
            elif type_choice == "NEUTRO":
                self.encounter_type.color = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
            elif type_choice == "HOSTIL":
                self.encounter_type.color = 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 1
            self.show_enemies.text += encounter + "\n\n"


class EncounterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EncounterApp().run()
```

What can I do to make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On way to do this is to keep a list of your `CheckBoxes` and the matching races. Then, in your `Gerar()` method, look at the `state` of each of those `CheckBoxes` to determine which races to include. In the modified code below, I have created a `self.race_choices` list. Each element of that list is a list of two elements, the `CheckBox` and the appropriate race. This information is used in the `Gerar()` method to create a the `available_races` list, which is then used in your `random.choice()` call.

```
import random
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.grid_2 = GridLayout()
        self.grid_2.cols = 2
        self.grid_2.size_hint = 1, 0.2
        self.grid_2.add_widget(Label(text="Number of enemies"))
        self.number = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.grid_2.add_widget(self.number)
        self.add_widget(self.grid_2)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Races", size_hint=(1,0.2)))

        self.grid_3 = GridLayout()
        self.grid_3.cols = 4
        self.grid_3.size_hint = 0.5, 0.5

        #  create a list of CheckBoxes and races
        self.race_choices = []

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Human"))
        self.chk_human = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_human)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_human, "Human"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Elf"))
        self.chk_elf = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_elf)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_elf, "Elf"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Dwarf"))
        self.chk_dwarf = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_dwarf)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_dwarf, "Dwarf"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Orc"))
        self.chk_orc = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_orc)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_orc, "Orc"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Hobbit"))
        self.chk_hobbit = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_hobbit)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_hobbit, "Hobbit"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Viashian"))
        self.chk_viashian = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_viashian)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_viashian, "Viahsian"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Goblin"))
        self.chk_goblin = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_goblin)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_goblin, "Goblin"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Leonim"))
        self.chk_leonin = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_leonin)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_leonin, "Leonin"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Nezumi"))
        self.chk_nezumi = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_nezumi)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_nezumi, "Nezumi"])

        self.grid_3.add_widget(Label(text="Naga"))
        self.chk_naga = CheckBox(active=True)
        self.grid_3.add_widget(self.chk_naga)
        self.race_choices.append([self.chk_naga, "Naga"])

        self.add_widget(self.grid_3)

        self.generate = Button(text="Generate", font_size=40, size_hint=(1,0.3))
        self.generate.background_color = 0.8,0.5,0.5,0.7
        self.generate.bind(on_press=self.Gerar)
        self.add_widget(self.generate)

        self.encounter_type = (Label(text="Type of encounter", font_size=20, size_hint=(1,0.1)))
        self.add_widget(self.encounter_type)
        self.show_enemies = Label(text="Click to Generate")
        self.add_widget(self.show_enemies)

    def Gerar(self, instance):
        self.show_enemies.text = ""
        int_number = int(self.number.text)
        type = ["NEUTRO", "HOSTIL", "ALIADO"]
        # races = ["HUMANO", "ELFO", "ANÃO", "HOBBIT", "VIASHINO", "LEONINO", "NEZUMI", "GOBLIN", "NAGA"]
        classes = ["FIGHTER", "KNIGHT", "BERSERKER", "FENCER", "NINJA", "HOPLITE", "BEAST TAMER",
                   "DRAGON TAMER", "ARCHER", "ROUGE", "DOLL MASTER", "WARLOCK", "MAGE", "ACOLYTE", "MONK", "CLERIC",
                   "BARD", "WARLORD", "SHAMAN", "DRUID", "SPEAKER", "MERCHANT", "ALCHEMIST", "BLACKSMITH", "CHEF"]
        elements = ["FIRE", "AIR", "WATER", "EARTH", "LIGHT", "DARK"]

        #  create a list of available races based on CheckBox state
        available_races = []
        for chkBox, race in self.race_choices:
            if chkBox.state == 'down':
                available_races.append(race)

        for i in range(int_number):
            type_choice = random.choice(type)
            race_choice = random.choice(available_races)
            class_choice = random.choice(classes)
            element_choice = random.choice(elements)
            encounter = (race_choice + ' : ' + class_choice + '  -  ' + element_choice)

            self.encounter_type.text = "ENCONTRO: " + type_choice
            if type_choice == "ALIADO":
                self.encounter_type.color = 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 1
            elif type_choice == "NEUTRO":
                self.encounter_type.color = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
            elif type_choice == "HOSTIL":
                self.encounter_type.color = 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 1
            self.show_enemies.text += encounter + "\n\n"


class EncounterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EncounterApp().run()
```

This can be done similarly using `kv`, but that makes the assembling of the `available_races` list a bit more difficult:

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Grid(GridLayout):

    def Gerar(self, instance):
        self.ids.show_enemies.text = ""
        int_number = int(self.ids.number.text)
        types = ["NEUTRO", "HOSTIL", "ALIADO"]
        classes = ["FIGHTER", "KNIGHT", "BERSERKER", "FENCER", "NINJA", "HOPLITE", "BEAST TAMER",
                   "DRAGON TAMER", "ARCHER", "ROUGE", "DOLL MASTER", "WARLOCK", "MAGE", "ACOLYTE", "MONK", "CLERIC",
                   "BARD", "WARLORD", "SHAMAN", "DRUID", "SPEAKER", "MERCHANT", "ALCHEMIST", "BLACKSMITH", "CHEF"]
        elements = ["FIRE", "AIR", "WATER", "EARTH", "LIGHT", "DARK"]

        # look at Widgets in grid_3 to determine which races are available
        # any change to grid_3 will break this
        available_races = []
        use_next_race = False
        for widget in self.ids.grid_3.children:
            if type(widget).__name__ == 'CheckBox':
                if widget.state == 'down':
                    use_next_race = True
                else:
                    use_next_race = False
            else:
                if use_next_race:
                    available_races.append(widget.text)

        for i in range(int_number):
            type_choice = random.choice(types)
            race_choice = random.choice(available_races)
            class_choice = random.choice(classes)
            element_choice = random.choice(elements)
            encounter = (race_choice + ' : ' + class_choice + '  -  ' + element_choice)

            self.ids.encounter_type.text = "ENCONTRO: " + type_choice
            if type_choice == "ALIADO":
                self.ids.encounter_type.color = 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 1
            elif type_choice == "NEUTRO":
                self.ids.encounter_type.color = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
            elif type_choice == "HOSTIL":
                self.ids.encounter_type.color = 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 1
            self.ids.show_enemies.text += encounter + "\n\n"

Builder.load_string('''
<Grid>:
    cols: 1
    GridLayout:
        id: grid_2
        cols: 2
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        Label:
            text: "Number of enemies"
        TextInput:
            id: number
            multiline: False

    Label:
        text: "Races"
        size_hint: (1,0.2)

    GridLayout:
        id: grid_3
        cols: 4
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5

        Label:
            text: "Human"
        CheckBox:
            id: Human
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Elf"
        CheckBox:
            id: Elf
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Dwarf"
        CheckBox:
            id: Dwarf
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Orc"
        CheckBox:
            id: Orc
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Hobbit"
        CheckBox:
            id: Hobbit
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Viashian"
        CheckBox:
            id: Viashian
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Goblin"
        CheckBox:
            id: Goblin
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Leonin"
        CheckBox:
            id: Leonin
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Nezumi"
        CheckBox:
            id: Nezumi
            active: True

        Label:
            text: "Naga"
        CheckBox:
            id: Naga
            active: True
    Button:
        text: "Generate"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: 1, 0.3
        on_press: root.Gerar(self)

    Label:
        id: encounter_type
        text: "Type of encounter"
        font_size: 20
        siz_hint: 1, 0.1

    Label:
        id: show_enemies
        text: "Click to Generate"
''')

class EncounterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EncounterApp().run()
```

All of the referencess to `Widgets` now use `ids`.

Comment: Thank you, John, you've helped me soo much! I had no idea I could use the append method

Comment: do you know how do I make the same thing but in kv language?